# Por que readlines mostra uma lista vazia mesmo com o arquivo tendo dados?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("grades.txt", "r")
for record in f.readlines():

    print(f"grade : {record} ")

print(f"readlines: {f.readlines()}")
f.close()
```

O arquivo grades.txt existe e possui o seguinte conteúdo:

```
10
9.8
.6
5.3
0
```

Por que ao alcançar a instrução:

```
print(f"readlines: {f.readlines()}
```

O programa exibe uma lista vazia? Ele teria que mostrar :

```
[10,9.8,.6,5.3,0]
```

O que está errado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) lê todo o conteúdo do arquivo, e quando você o chama novamente, não há mais nada a ser lido.

Se quer guardar as linhas para usá-las depois, basta usar `readlines` apenas uma vez e guardar o resultado em uma lista, e usar esta lista nas vezes seguintes:

```
with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
    linhas = f.readlines()

for record in linhas:
    print(f"grade : {record} ")

print(f"readlines: {linhas}")
```

Repare no uso de [`with`](http://v), que já garante que o arquivo será fechado ao final, mesmo se ocorrer algum erro durante a leitura (assim você não precisa chamar `close`).

---

Note também que isso não tem **nada** a ver com "*o arquivo ficar ocupado pelo programa*", como afirmava [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443468/112052) (que foi apagada). O que acontece é que existe um "ponteiro interno" que indica a posição em que você está no arquivo, e a cada vez que você lê algo dele, esse ponteiro vai avançando posições. E como `readlines` lê todo o conteúdo, após chamá-lo este "ponteiro" estará no final do arquivo (por isso qualquer chamada feita depois não encontra mais nada).

Mas você pode retroceder para o início do arquivo (usando [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)) e ler novamente (**embora não tenha lá muita utilidade neste caso**):

```
with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
    for record in f.readlines() # ler o arquivo uma vez
        # ... faz o que quiser com record

    f.seek(0) # voltar ao início
    print(f.readlines()) # ler de novo
```

Como eu já disse, nesse caso não faz o menor sentido ler o arquivo de novo. Use a primeira solução, que só lê uma vez e pronto.

---

Só um detalhe: `readlines` mantém as quebras de linha do arquivo, então ao imprimir com `print(f"grade : {record} ")`, você acabará pulando 2 linhas: uma referente à quebra de linha existente no arquivo, e outra que o `print` adiciona automaticamente. Ou seja, o primeiro código imprimirá:

```
grade: linha 1

grade: linha 2

etc...
```

Se quiser remover estas quebras de linha "extras", você pode mudar o parâmetro no `print`, ou removê-lo da própria linha:

```
for record in linhas:
    print(f"grade : {record} ", end="")

# ou
for record in linhas:
    record = record.rstrip('\n')
    print(f"grade : {record} ")
```

Lembrando que no primeiro caso, a última linha não terá a quebra de linha depois (caso a última linha não-vazia do arquivo não tenha uma quebra de linha). Já no segundo caso, todas as linhas terão uma quebra de linha adicionada.

Outra alternativa é já criar a lista sem essas quebras de linha:

```
with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
    # remove a quebra de linha de todas as linhas
    linhas = [ linha.rstrip('\n') for linha in f.readlines() ]

for record in linhas:
    print(f"grade : {record} ")
```

---

Vale lembrar também que `readlines` sempre carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória de uma vez, o que pode ser um problema para arquivos muito grandes. Se você precisa mesmo ter uma lista com todas as linhas, aí não tem muito o que fazer. Mas se só quer ler as linhas (e fazer algo com elas) e não precisa guardá-las, aí é melhor ler linha a linha:

```
with open("grades.txt", "r") as f:
    for linha in f: # assim você lê uma linha de cada vez
        # faz o que precisar com a linha
```

Answer (score 2):

Os métodos de leitura [`read()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_read.asp), [`readline()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp) e [`readlines()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp) realizam a leitura do texto apenas uma vez, ou melhor, realizam a leitura de ondem eles têm parado.

```
file.read(3) # Lê até o 3º caractere do arquivo            (Texto: "Hel")
file.read() # Continua a partir do 4º caractere do arquivo (Texto: "lo World")
```

Logo se você realizar a leitura completa do arquivo, ao chamar um desses três métodos na próxima vez, ele retornará uma string ou lista vazia, pois não haverá mais nada para ler.

O que você deve fazer é utilizar o método [`seek()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_seek.asp) que volta para um ponto do arquivo. Dessa forma, você pode realizar a leitura mais uma vez. Exemplo:

```
file.read() # Lê todo arquivo                                      (Texto: "Hello World")
file.read() # Devolve string vazia pois ele já leu todo o arquivo  (Texto: "")

file.seek(3) # Volta para o 4º caractere
file.read() # Lê todo o texto a partir do 4º caractere             (Texto: "lo World")
```

Sabendo agora de tudo isso, basta você adicionar o método no seu código, passando o valor zero como parâmetro para ele ler do início. Veja como ficaria:

```
f = open("grades.txt", "r")

for record in f.readlines():
    print(f"grade : {record} ")

f.seek(0)

print(f"readlines: {f.readlines()}")
f.close()
```

---

Ainda assim, não acho que essa seja uma boa forma de se trabalhar com arquivos, pois ao utilizar os métodos `seek` e `read`, você estaria realizando a leitura novamente do seu arquivo de forma desnecessária.

Imagine que você possui um arquivo contendo megabytes em texto. Você gostaria mesmo de realizar a leitura novamente do seu arquivo, tendo o lido uma vez ?

A solução ideal para **seu caso específico** (algumas vezes o arquivo pode ser muito grande, e talvez você prefira trocar memória por processamento ou vice-versa) seria criar uma variável para guardar o texto que você leu. Exemplo:

```
f = open("grades.txt", "r")

lines = f.readlines()

for record in lines:
    print(f"grade : {record} ")

print(f"readlines: {lines}")
f.close()
```